# Regular expression behaves differently in Find in Files and in Search current file

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to find all strings in my code, while excluding stuff like AssemblyInfo.cs files, comments and XML content.

I've come up with a regular expression which works when I use it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, however when trying to use it with the "Find in Files" dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), it delivers an arbitrary result, including even empty lines and lines which only contain e.g. an opening curly brace {.

Is this a bug in VS2013? I unfortunately don't have other versions available to test this behavior.

Here is the regular expression and its explanation:

```
^[^\[/<]*\".*\"

^: Start of line
[^\[/<]*: Any amount of characters which are not [, / or <
\".*\": Any amount of characters enclosed by two quotation marks
```

When using it with the regular search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), this properly detects lines like

```
  "This is a test"
  someObject->doSomething("This is a test");
```

and intentionally does not detect lines like the following:

```
 [assembly: AssemblyTitle("....")]
 /// <param name="Test">Test</param>
```

However, when I'm using the "Find in Files" dialog, the same expression lists the full implementation of some methods including lines with only braces, class definitions and empty lines.

Do I have to use a different syntax or anything with Find in Files, or does it not support the same features as when searching within one file?

[Edit:]
Note that leaving out the [...] expression works as intended in both search dialogs

[Edit2:]
VS Version is "Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013, Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3"

Comment: Try [`(?m)^\[?[^\[/<]*".*"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%5e%5c%5b%3f%5b%5e%5c%5b%2f%3c%5d*%22.*%22&i=%22This+is+a+test%22%0d%0a++someObject-%3edoSomething(%22This+is+a+test%22)%3b).

Comment: Actually, Find in Files and Find dialogs use the same regex syntax, and the only trouble is matching newlines (when you need to use `\r` explicitly). Please also check the options you are enabling/disabling.

Comment: @stribizhev Same issue, it works perfectly with Ctrl+F but produces the same weird result when used with Ctrl+Shift+F. I'Ve tried replacing `.*` by `[^\r\n]*` to make sure it does not match line breaks, but it didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression part `[^\[/<]*` apparently matches line breaks in the "Find in Files" dialog, unlike the regular Find dialog.

The problem can be solved by explicitly excluding `\n` both in this part of the expression and between the quotes:

```
Full Expression: ^[^\n\[/<]*"[^\n]*"
```

The [`(?m)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) modifier is probably not supported by Visual Studio 2013, it seems to be ignored, at least in this example.